# HTTP calls fail only on internal corp network using rest-client

Tags: python, ruby, api, http, rest-client

HTTP calls fail on internal corp network using rest-client. I tried using other Ruby library like Net::HTTP etc but it fails too. This issue started happening a week back. It was working fine for a year. I tried using python libraries(requests, urllib2). It didn't work on requests but strangely worked on urllib2. Not really sure what is happening behind. All HTTP calls work fine from browser when headers are passed, its just the libraries

Please find below the sample code that fails

`def get_data
    Yajl::Parser.parse(RestClient::Resource.new("url", @header).get)
end`

Please find below the error that rest-client library throws

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext. [Images of plaintext are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). You have access to the plaintext; please copy and paste it into your question.

Comment: Have you looked to see if any new firewalls/firewall rules have been enabled? I've seen some in the past that were as simple as checking for the USER_AGENT, which a browser would report as a browser. Some libraries report as something other than a browser (or nothing at all). I'd try passing along a browser-looking USER_AGENT in your request just to see

Comment: I recommend trying to make it work with Postman, because it has a  command to export the query to many different libraries.

Comment: Postman is a good idea. Similarly you could try using curl from the command line. There's really nothing special about Ruby's HTTP lib. If basic attempts with it are not working, chances are your working examples (browser, urllib2) are doing some extra magic to make the connection happen.

Comment: Thanks guys for suggestions. I tried passing user agent but no luck. Postman and curl are working fine. I also copied code from Postman and executed it but doesn't work. Its weird one. Debugging further

Comment: Looks like IPv6 proxies were introduced last week, which is blocking the calls made by libraries. Did some research on how browser makes calls. Looks like browsers will try to connect over IPv6, but if they don't get a working connection within 300 milliseconds they will try to connect over IPv4. I'm seeing how to force rest-client library to connect over IPv4 instead of IPv6. Any ideas?